# Why does jquery need a selector for a ui dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-selectors, jquery-dialog

I understand that jquery needs a selector to work with it like a class="x" on all links with class="x".

But what I do not understand is why does jquery need a selector like #dialog that points to a div because the dialog is doing nothing with the div.

In my opinion a window/dialog should have nothing to do with a div because the dialog is over all other ui elements.

sample:

```
<div id="dialog"> what is that div for?</div>
$('#dialog').dialog({...
```

Comment: the dialog it's build base on the div, so to create the dialog jquery need to know which div it's going to be the dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialog element is acting as a container.  When you open the dialog, it displays the contents of that container.  You can always dynamically generate the content and display that, but using a container allows you to define the content first (and say, hide it), before you want to display/render it.

Comment: So where should I put this div-container for the dialog? I have on the left a div1 and at the right a div2 and at the top a buttonbardiv. Where should I put that dialogDiv ?

Comment: Well, you can specify the position of the rendered dialog, so as a result, the position of its contents do not really matter.  Place it somewhere that makes sense, keep it hidden, and then render + position it as needed.